# how to create shell command 'd' as equivalent to 'drush'?

Tags: drush

Typing "drush" over and over again, I find it is quite time consuming.  How can I shorten the command so I can just type "d"?

I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: Links aren't answers, so here's a comment: http://www.coolestguyplanet.net/make-an-alias-in-bash-shell-in-os-x-terminal/

Comment: One reason links aren't answers is that links rot.  That link being a case in point. http://www.ilxor.com/ILX/ThreadSelectedControllerServlet?boardid=40&threadid=74037&bookmarkedmessageid=823478

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Drush-5 (recommended), then see [examples/example.bashrc](http://drupalcode.org/project/drush.git/blob/HEAD:/examples/example.bashrc) for a bunch of very useful ways to enhance your experience in your shell when using Drush.  Installation instructions are in the file.  One of the things it does is create an alias 'dr' for Drush; if you wanted this to be 'd' on your system, it would be easy enough to make that change.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in Bash (or Zsh or Ksh or whatever) you can create an alias.  Type

```
alias d=drush
```

on the command line for an ephemeral alias (that will go away when you close your shell).  To have the alias permanently available, add that same line to a startup file.  That would be `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` if you use Bash, `.zshrc` if you use Z shell, etc.  If you're on OS X and haven't changed your shell, you're using Bash (unless you're on a *very* old version of OS X).

An advantage to creating shell aliases is that you can create similar aliases for any other shell command you want, not limited to Drush commands.  The advantage to creating Drush aliases (IIRC) is that you can create Drush 'subcommand' aliases, which you can't do with shell aliases.   E.g. `drush perform-my-secret-command` or whatever.